# please tell me how do I fix this code down here(please tell in my easy English)

Tags: arduino-uno

```
 LiquidCrystal 1cd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

 void setup() {
   1cd.begin(16, 2);
   1cd.print"abbu, kya, chalrelaye!");
 }

 void loop() {

 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Variable names MUST NOT start with a digit. Only '_' and a-z are allowed!

`1cd` really should be `lcd` with an 'ell' instead of a one (1).

Comment: what did we learn here about Arduino? upvoters, how is this useful for you?

Comment: The compiler for Arduino is just working the way as any other C/C++ compiler. ;)

Comment: I down-vote Answers to a Question originating in an typographical error, because this kind of question has no value and without answer it would be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you modify the LiquidCrystal "Hello World" sketch:

[image: drop down menu used to open the sketch]

Here is the example code:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

Good luck!